# Access property without creating a new empty instance c#

Tags: c#

I have a class P as part of namespace D with several fields and related properties

```
namespace Driver
[Export(typeof (P))]
public class Pilot : Send
{
    private bool _b1;
    ...

public bool B1
{
get { return _b1; }
private set
    {
        if (_b1 != value)
            {
                _b1 = value;
                NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => B1);
            }
         }
     }
```

And then another class in the same namespace with some methods

```
namespace Driver
    public class PilotEng
    {
        public void Statistics()
            {
            ....
            }

        public void Running()
            {
            ....
            }
```

What is the best way to access and use the parameters of class P in class PE methods?

Comment: It's not clear at all what you mean - how are `P` and `PE` related?  Does `PE` _contain_ a `P` or _is it_ a subtype of `P`?

Comment: You can use meaningful names to make it clear. And If I didn't misunderstand what you are asking. You are looking for abstract class.

Comment: you can use `static` properties without an instance... but it's unclear what your actually having an issue with

Comment: @DStanley P and PE (pilot and PilotEng) are part of same namespace as mentioned in the question.

Comment: @Berkay, names are now edited, could you give more elaboration?

Comment: @user1993000 That doesn't explain how they are related - so it's not clear if composition, inheritance, or some other pattern is appropriate.  What does `PilotEng` do and how does it use/need the properties of `Pilot`?

Comment: @Kritner the pattern does not allow using static.

Comment: "because they're in the same namespace" does not mean they are related.  You could have your entire assembly in a single namespace.  Ever seen `System.Web`?  So much unrelated stuff within a single namespace :P

Comment: you could have `PilotEng` reference a specific instance of `Pilot` or a collection of them, or vice versa.  Or maybe perhaps because you listed notify property changed information, you're looking for a way to subscribe to that event from `PilotEng`?

Comment: @DStanley PilotEng need the properties from Pilot to update some internal parameters (i.e. internal model).

Comment: @Kritner how would you implement the specific instance of Pilot?

Comment: @user1993000 it depends on what you're trying to do... which is not clear... so I'm not sure how to help.

Comment: @kritner i want to access the propertoes of Pilot class in PulotEng class through an instance.

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways for `PilotEng` to access information from `Pilot`.

Pass in instance of `Pilot` at `PilotEng` construction:

```
public class PilotEng
{
    private Pilot myPilot;

    public PilotEng(Pilot pilot)
    {
        myPilot = pilot;
    }

    public void Statistics()
        {
            var whatever = myPilot.B1;
        ....
        }

    public void Running()
        {
        ....
        }
}
```

somewhere else...

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    Pilot p = new Pilot();
    PilotEng pe = new PilotEng(p);
    pe.Statistics();
}
```

update your method signature(s) to take in an instance of pilot to work with:

```
public class PilotEng
{

    public void Statistics(Pilot pilot)
        {
            var whatever = pilot.B1;
        ....
        }

    public void Running()
        {
        ....
        }
}
```

somewhere else...

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    Pilot p = new Pilot();
    PilotEng pe = new PilotEng();
    pe.Statistics(p);
}
```

Both are valid, one may be more valid than another, and there are several other ways to accomplish this.  It all depends on what you're actually trying to do.

Comment: Thanks the using the instance was the solution.